# Javascript Challenge: Loops - Multiple Conditions - stuck and can't figure this out

Tags: javascript, loops, conditional-statements

I did this module on functions and execution context - all questions have gone well but there is one challenge I have spent a lot of time on and still can't figure it out. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Challenge question says:
Write a function `addingAllTheWeirdStuff` which adds the sum of all the odd numbers in array2 to each element under 10 in array1.

Similarly, `addingAllTheWeirdStuff` should also add the sum of all the even numbers in array2 to those elements over 10 in array1.

**BONUS**: If any element in array2 is greater than 20, add 1 to every element in array1.

```js
// Uncomment these to check your work!
// console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); // expected log [10, 12, 14, 23, 21]
// console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22])); // expected log [11, 13, 15, 46, 44, 11]

// my attempt so far:
function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
  let result = []
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] > 20) {
      result = array1[i] += 1
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 === 0 && array1[i] > 10) {
      result = array1[i] + array2[i]
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    if (array2[i] % 2 !== 0 && array1[i] < 10) {
      result = array1[i] + array2[i]
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (please take the [tour]) - it seems that you have not indicated what your issue is.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, there are comments of 'expected log' next to the console log.. that's what I'm supposed to be getting but I'm not getting those arrays as my answers, rather I'm just getting 8, and 8 as my two answers.. very far off, and not even arrays.

Comment: One problem is you are overwriting `result` with values instead of adding a value to the array, eg `result = array1[i] += 1`. You can add to an array by using `push(value)` eg `result.push(array1[i]+1)`

Comment: Thank you Patrick.. I did think this is a problem. I tried .push into the array but this also doesn't work. Only other thing I can think of is creating a sum variable and adding all the results to this sum but then this also isn't working when trying to get sum into array.
using .push for all the results gets me with:
[21, 2, 8]
[2, 21, 2, 8]

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using `reduce` and `map` array method, with the ternary operator:

```js
const array1 = [1, 3, 5, 17, 15];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2) {

    const oddSum = array2.reduce((sum, current) => current % 2 ? current + sum : 0 + sum, 0)
    const oddEven = array2.reduce((sum, current) => current % 2 == 0 ? current + sum : 0 + sum, 0)

    return array1.map(num => num < 10 ? num + oddSum : num + oddEven)

}

console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff(array1, array2))
```

Comment: Thank you :) need to study up on these methods!!

Comment: Thank you! If my solution helped you, you can upvote it, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Awesome! So it worked for the first console log in my question, but not for the second one. The console logs were given as part of the question with the expected logs but didn't get the second one using this. (the expected answers are commented out at top of my quesiton)

Answer (score 0):

If you break the challenge into smaller pieces, you can deconstruct it better and come up with your solutions.

This is what I did... I will be adding more comments shortly with more explanations

I chose to keep using loops as I assumed this was the point of the challenges (to practice for loops, multiple conditions, etc) - In other words, I chose to not use `map / reduce` on purpose but if that's allowed, use the answer by @charmful0x as it results in less code :)

```js
// function to get sum of all odd numbers in array
function getSumOfAllOddNumbersInArray( elementArray ){
  var sumOfOddNumbers = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
    // use remainder operator to find out if element is odd or not
    if (elementArray[i] % 2 !== 0 ) {
      sumOfOddNumbers += elementArray[i];
    }
  }
  
  return sumOfOddNumbers;
}

// function to get sum of all EVEN numbers in array
function getSumOfAllEvenNumbersInArray( elementArray ){
  var sumOfEvenNumbers = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
    // use remainder operator to find out if element is odd or not
    if (elementArray[i] % 2 === 0 ) {
      sumOfEvenNumbers += elementArray[i];
    }
  }
  
  return sumOfEvenNumbers;
}

// Return true if there is at least one element in array that is greater than 20
function hasElementOverTwenty( elementArray ){
  for (let i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
    if (elementArray[i] > 20 ) {
      // no need to keep looping, we found one - exit function
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}


function addingAllTheWeirdStuff( firstArray, secondArray ){
  var sumOfOddNumbersInArray = getSumOfAllOddNumbersInArray( secondArray );
  var sumOfEvenNumbersInArray = getSumOfAllEvenNumbersInArray( secondArray );
  var needToAddOne = hasElementOverTwenty( secondArray );
    
  for (let i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
    // Challenge One
    if (firstArray[i] < 10) {
      firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] + sumOfOddNumbersInArray;       
      
    } else if (firstArray[i] > 10) {
    // Challenge Two
      firstArray[i] = firstArray[i] + sumOfEvenNumbersInArray;       
    }
    
    // bonus
    if( needToAddOne ){
      firstArray[i]++;
    }   
  }
  
  return firstArray;
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); 
console.log('expected:' + [10, 12, 14, 23, 21] );
console.log(addingAllTheWeirdStuff([1, 3, 5, 17, 15, 1], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 22]));
console.log('expected:' + [11, 13, 15, 46, 44, 11] );
```

```html
Challenge question says: Write a function addingAllTheWeirdStuff which adds the sum of all the odd numbers in array2 to each element under 10 in array1.

Similarly, addingAllTheWeirdStuff should also add the sum of all the even numbers in array2 to those elements over 10 in array1.

BONUS: If any element in array2 is greater than 20, add 1 to every element in array1.
```